# Eclipse XML formatting breaks / changes value of list of Spring XML

Tags: eclipse, spring

I have a spring list defined in xml as -

```
<list>
    <value> </value>
</list>
```

However, Eclipse (Juno) has decided to format it as -

```
<list>
    <value>
    </value>
</list>
```

Therefore, changing my value to space + line break for any developer that might format the XML using Eclipse.

I don't want to change the Eclipse formatting rules, but how do I change the Spring XML to avoid this issue?  Is there an attribute I can use instead to store the value?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the schema, or use xml:space. http://www.simonstl.com/xmlprim/xmlupdate/atts.html